# Junk values when using fixed size array whereas if I use dynamically sized array the results are correct

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

void readMatrix(int m,int n,int a[][n]);
void displayMatrix(int m,int n,int a[][n]);
void addMatrix(int m,int n,int a[][n],int b[][n]);

int main()
{
    int a[5][5],b[5][5],m,n,p,q;
    printf("Enter the no. of rows and columns of matrix A\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);

    printf("Enter the no. of rows and columns of matrix B\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);

    if(m!=p||n!=q)
    {
        printf("Matrix addition not possible\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Enter %d elements to matrix A\n",m*n);
    readMatrix(m,n,a);

    printf("Enter %d elements to matrix B\n",m*n);
    readMatrix(p,q,b);

    printf("Matrix A\n");
    displayMatrix(m,n,a);

    printf("Matrix B\n");
    displayMatrix(p,q,b);

    addMatrix(m,n,a,b); 
}

void readMatrix(int m,int n,int a[m][n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void displayMatrix(int m,int n,int a[m][n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void addMatrix(int m,int n,int a[m][n],int b[m][n])
{
    int c[5][5]; //I guess this is causing problem
    //int c[m][n]; //gives correct answer
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("Sum Matrix\n");

    /*Gives correct result
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    */

    displayMatrix(m,n,c);
}
```

> `displayMatrix(m,n,c)` is correct If i define array as `c[m][n]`, code for it is given above.
>
> It is giving junk value if I use `c[5][5]`.

I'm using gcc compiler. I displayed the sum in `addMatrix` function itself, which gives correct result. Not able to figure out the mistake. Kindly help. Thank You.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: A `int c[5][5];` is not the same as a `int c[3][3];`, especially when you pass it to a function and tell the compiler that it is a `int c[3][3];`.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. But then, matrices A and B are displaying properly. In the main function, even they are defined as a[5][5] and b[5][5]

Comment: In addition to the MCVE already mentioned by Jabberwocky above, please provide your input, actual output and expected output. Especially when your problem is realted to wrong output.

Comment: Thank You.
Below given is the actual output

Enter the no. of rows and columns of matrix A
2 2
Enter the no. of rows and columns of matrix B
2 2
Enter 4 elements to matrix A
1 2 3 4
Enter 4 elements to matrix B
1 2 3 4
Matrix A
1 2 
3 4 
Matrix B
1 2 
3 4 
**Sum Matrix
2 4 
-719505381 32574 

Expected Output is: (for Sum Matrix)
2 4
6 8**

Comment: You should add this to the question. With this important information it is clear that you do not use an array that matches your `c[5][5]` array.

Comment: @mch understood your statement. Thank you for the reply.